# Display random text line on screen from a defined list with time intervals

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a list of text lines. I need a way to display each text line on screen randomly, at a certain configurable time interval. The whole list needs to be repeated endless until manual stop. Each line may appear more than one time.

The first thing that comes to mind is MS PowerPoint. It's animated, allows full screen and has nice graphics. I know it also has Macro's to automate things. But how do I repeatedly randomize strings with it?

It doesn't need to be MS PowerPoint, if there is a better alternative, you're welcome to add.

Comment: Many screen savers have a feature to randomly display images from a list.

Comment: You could also save them as images, and use the default background screen to show them. See http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/create-a-desktop-background-slide-show